# What is the difference between WithIsoIntervalConverter() and WithIsoDateIntervalConverter()?

Tags: nodatime

I have recently began using [NodaTime](https://nodatime.org/), and wanted to use the [JSON.NET serializer settings](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet/) which come with it. There is however one thing I do not understand and fail to find in the documentation.

From what I understand, the following exists now:

```
ConfigureForNodaTime()
    // Disable automatic conversion of anything that looks like a date and time to BCL types.
    settings.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None;
    converters.Add(NodaConverters.InstantConverter);
    converters.Add(NodaConverters.IntervalConverter);
    converters.Add(NodaConverters.LocalDateConverter);
    converters.Add(NodaConverters.LocalDateTimeConverter);
    converters.Add(NodaConverters.LocalTimeConverter);
    converters.Add(NodaConverters.DateIntervalConverter);
    converters.Add(NodaConverters.OffsetConverter);
    converters.Add(NodaConverters.CreateDateTimeZoneConverter(provider));
    converters.Add(NodaConverters.DurationConverter);
    converters.Add(NodaConverters.RoundtripPeriodConverter);
    converters.Add(NodaConverters.OffsetDateTimeConverter);
    converters.Add(NodaConverters.CreateZonedDateTimeConverter(provider));

.WithIsoIntervalConverter()
    ReplaceExistingConverters<Interval>(settings.Converters, NodaConverters.IsoIntervalConverter);

.WithIsoDateIntervalConverter()
    ReplaceExistingConverters<DateInterval>(settings.Converters, NodaConverters.IsoDateIntervalConverter);
```

What is not clear to me, do I have to pick between `WithIsoIntervalConverter` and `WithIsoDateIntervalConverter`, or do I need to use both like `ConfigureForNodaTime().WithIsoIntervalConverter().WithIsoDateIntervalConverter()`? Or do I simply not have to use any of them and just use `ConfigureForNodaTime()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WithIsoIntervalConverter` replaces the converter for the `Interval` type.

`WithIsoDateIntervalConverter` replaces the converter for the `DateInterval` type.

If you're not using `Interval` or `DateInterval`, you won't care what the converter does with them. If you *are* using either or both of those types, you need to think about how you want them to be serialized.

To stick with `DateInterval` for example, the default serialization format (as configured by `ConfigureForNodaTime`) produces JSON like this:

```
"value": { "Start": "2018-03-15" End: "2018-04-01" }
```

However, if you're trying to interoperate with code that expects an ISO representation of date intervals, you can use `WithIsoDateIntervalConverter()` and the serialized data will look like this instead:

```
"value": "2018-03-15/2018-04-01"
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't knew there was an ISO for ranges.